How to draw multicolor curve with smooth gradient in l3draw?
description
I've see two questions about draw multicolor curve with smooth gradient in this site:

How to draw an arrow with two colors?
tikz: draw multicolor curve with smooth gradient

Since i am more familar with l3draw and LaTeX3. I want to use l3draw to create such gradient curve.
what i've try
i can create a shaded region using l3draw, like that:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% => region shade
\cs_set:Npn \color_step:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {blue!#1!green} 
}

\draw_begin:
  \draw_path_circle:nn {3cm, 3cm}{3cm}
  \draw_path_use_clear:n {clip}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn {0}{2}{100}{
    \draw_scope_begin:
      \color_step:n {#1}
      \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn {(#1/20)cm, 0cm}{((#1+20)/20)cm, 6cm}
      \draw_path_use_clear:n {fill}
    \draw_scope_end:
  }
\draw_end:
\end{document}

this code would create a region below:

so i want to create the gradient curve in the same way (by spliting the curve into many small segments, use a loop to draw these segements). Then i write the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% => region shade
\cs_set:Npn \color_step:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {blue!#1!green} 
}

% ==> curve shade: y=0.5*x+1
\draw_begin:
  \draw_path_moveto:n {0, 0}
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn {0}{0.1}{4}{
    \draw_scope_begin:
      \exp_args:Nx \color_step:n {\fp_eval:n {#1*25}}
      \draw_path_moveto:n {#1 cm, (0.5*#1+1)cm}
      \draw_path_lineto:n {(#1+1) cm, (0.5*(#1+1)+1)cm}
      \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
    \draw_scope_end:
  }
\draw_end:
\end{document}

this code gives the result

but things become weird when this curve is not a straight line, like y=sin(x). The following code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% => region shade
\cs_set:Npn \color_step:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {blue!#1!green} 
}

% ==> curve shade:y=sin(x)
\draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_matrix:nnnn {1.5}{0}{0}{1.5}
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn {0}{0.05*\c_pi_fp}{2*\c_pi_fp}{
    \draw_scope_begin:
      \exp_args:Nx \color_step:n {\fp_eval:n {#1*(100/2/\c_pi_fp)}}
      \draw_path_moveto:n {#1 cm,  (sin(#1)) cm}
      \draw_path_lineto:n {(#1+1) cm, (sin(#1+1))cm}
      \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
    \draw_scope_end:
  }
\draw_end:
\end{document}

gives the result:

The end of the previous segment is not connected to the beginning of the next segment.
I think the reason maybe "these segements is not a Complete path". I try to construst a complete path Consisting of a group of segement with different colors, then draw this path at the end of the code using \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}. After i write a simple code
\draw_begin:
  \draw_path_moveto:n {0, 0}
  \color_group_begin:
    \color_select:n {red}
    \draw_path_lineto:n {2cm, 2cm}
  \color_group_end:
  \color_group_begin:
    \color_select:n {blue}
    \draw_path_lineto:n {4cm, 0cm}
  \color_group_end:
  \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
\draw_end:

stroke color of the output path is all black, none of these \color_select:n {} command working.

i've also let \color_select:n out of group, but still can't have to colors in the curve. Plus, command \color_stroke:n is not working obviously.

finally
Can this problem be solved using l3draw? Or can be solved with the help of other packages?

Currently 'no' as gradients need PDF management and I still have to work out if we want to do that generically or only in LaTeX ...

Thanks anyway. That being said, I don't actually use this feature very often.

Your line segments are always moving 1 along the x axis, but you want to move the step size, so that the end of one line segment starts were the last one finished

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% => region shade
\cs_set:Npn \color_step:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {blue!#1!green} 
}

% ==> curve shade:y=sin(x)
\draw_begin:
  \draw_transform_matrix:nnnn {1.5}{0}{0}{1.5}
  \fp_step_inline:nnnn {0}{0.05*\c_pi_fp}{2*\c_pi_fp}{
    \draw_scope_begin:
    \draw_cap_round:
    \exp_args:Nx \color_step:n {\fp_eval:n {#1*(100/2/\c_pi_fp)}}
      \draw_path_moveto:n {#1 cm,  (sin(#1)) cm}
      \draw_path_lineto:n {(#1+(0.05*\c_pi_fp)) cm, (sin(#1+(0.05*\c_pi_fp)))cm}
      \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
    \draw_scope_end:
  }
\draw_end:
\end{document}

I kept with lines here, you could use a quadratic bezier approximation instead for a smoother path.

Oh, i forget to move these segements the step size. Besides, add command \draw_cap_round: make the output curve look better.

@zongpingding updated as suggested
